# Connect IMAP to Android .any example

Tags: android

any example of IMAP and if possible source code of IMAP and Android.

Answer (score 2):

http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label%3AAndroid+IMAP&projectsearch=Search+projects

```
protected InputStream getContentStream() throws MessagingException {
    InputStream is = null;
    boolean pk = message.getPeek(); // acquire outisde of message cache lock

    // Acquire MessageCacheLock, to freeze seqnum.
    synchronized(message.getMessageCacheLock()) {
        try {
            IMAPProtocol p = message.getProtocol();

            // Check whether this message is expunged
            message.checkExpunged();

            if (p.isREV1() && (message.getFetchBlockSize() != -1))
               return new IMAPInputStream(message, sectionId, bs.size, pk);
            // Else, vanila IMAP4, no partial fetch

            int seqnum = message.getSequenceNumber();
            BODY b;
            if (pk)
               b = p.peekBody(seqnum, sectionId);
            else
               b = p.fetchBody(seqnum, sectionId);
            if (b != null)
               is = b.getByteArrayInputStream();
         } catch (ConnectionException cex) {
            throw new FolderClosedException(
            message.getFolder(), cex.getMessage());
         } catch (ProtocolException pex) {
            throw new MessagingException(pex.getMessage(), pex);
         }
```

[refer this](http://www.google.com/codesearch#ojJ6TKlKTCM/trunk/mail/src/java/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPBodyPart.java)

Comment: svn checkout http://javamail-android.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ javamail-android-read-only